# I can't erase register in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to erase records in a Pandas DataFrame with Nan values.

I'm using the next code:

```
df_trabajo = df

condicion1 = df_trabajo['Cap-shape'].isnull()
df_trabajo = df_trabajo[~condicion1]

condicion2 = df_trabajo['Cap-surface'].isnull()
df_trabajo = df_trabajo[~condicion2]

df_trabajo
```

But I get an error: "KeyError: 'Cap-surface'"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da7o6.jpg)

Please your help. Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your dataframe does not have a 'Cap-surface' column. This is a separate issue from what you are asking. To erase records with Nan values, try

```py
df_trabajo = df_trabajo.dropna()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your dataframe df_trabajo has 'Cap-surface' column name.
df_trabajo = df_trabajo[~condicion1]
this will over write your data frame, so 'Cap-surface' will not be present here

Comment: The column has a blank before the "C", that's problem. THANKS!!!